# i have 2 tables (expenses , expdescription) my question is how to show expenses in table grouped by expenses description

Tags: php, sql

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
       {
        //$sql3 ='select * from description where descid = '.$row['descid'].' ';
        $query3 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql3);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3);
        $total =$total + $row['amount'];
        echo ' <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center">'.$row['amount'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">'.$row2['description'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">'.$row['info'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">'.$row['DATE'].'</td>
        <td style="text-align:center">'.$total.'</td>';

      
        ?>
        <td><a href="insert.php?delete=<?php echo $row['outid']; ?>"
        class ="btn btn-danger">delete</a></td>
        <?php
        echo '
        </tr>';
       
     }
    }
```

this code show me all data from expenses  table  but
how to write php code to . show all expenses grouped by expense description .

Comment: Your problem is less the php code but the SQL query.  Have you tried to formulate your SQL query in PHPMyAdmin or is this your re<l problem that you have no knowledge of SQL?  To be able to help you we would need the table structure of both tables (you can get this also with PHPMyAdmin.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate another array grouped by description or just query another SQL statement, that reads out the grouped rows. Since you have all the data queried already I 'd suggest a simple array grouped by description.

```
$grouped = [];
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

foreach ($data as $row) {
    if (!isset($grouped[$row['description'])) {
        $grouped[$row['description]] = 0;
    }

    $grouped[$row['description'] += $row['amount'];
}

// process your templating here
foreach ($data as $row) {
    ...
}
```

Anayway ... another solution could be a simple SQL Statement.

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum FROM table WHERE description_id = :description_id
```